# Passive vs. Active voice in Present Simple

Tags: passive-voice, present-tense, active-voice, present-simple

What would be the passive voice of the following sentence?

> She opens window frequently.

Is this correct?

> Window is opened frequently.

Comment: Your first sentence isn't correct. There should be an article before "window", in this case probably "the".

Answer (score 3):

> She opens the window frequently.

Becomes:

> The window is opened frequently.

Or:

> The window is opened by her frequently.

Note that you need the article before "window". As seen in the first passive voice example above, the passive voice can be used to obscure *who* is performing the action.

Comment: @zondo: how do we know it's not the passenger window in a car?

Comment: @zondo: I didn't notice that Era had originally written "the windows is".